# How should I secure my card details form?

Tags: php, linux, security, apache, ssl

The process:

1. User enters card num, expiry
   etc on a form on my site
2. Sent to a form_process.php on my server which accesses the payment API (in my case [Chargify](http://www.chargify.com))
3. API sends to external card processor (Chargify)

What security measures do i need to take in addition to acquiring an `SSL certificate` and ensuring the form page and the form_process.php are using `https` ?

Answer (score 2):

There are very few sites to whom I would provide my credit card details - but there are lots of payment processing services (paypal, worldpay, google) which provide third-party payment services where they handle all the secure data. A quick look at the Chargify site suggests they offer a similar service. I would **very strongly recommend** that you change to such a service and do not process credit card details on your own site.

Have a google for 'PCI DSS' - if you are capturing credit card details then you should be compliant with the specification.

Comment: thanks this is interesting, unfortunately there are some essential features that we cannot do with Chargify's hosted pages. Any more thoughts on this would be most appreciated. We will not be storing the credit card details ourselves, but sending them to Chargify's API.

Comment: They will exist for a short time at least in the memory on your server (which is marginally better than writing them to disk) but you still need to take appropriate measures to protect the data - and for preference shouldn't capture it on your site at all.

Answer (score -2):

Check if $_SERVER["HTTPS"] is on, and check $_SERVER["SSL_SERVER_M_SERIAL"]

Comment: the question is looking for measures **in addition** to ssk and https

Comment: My reputation is 1. Decrease it:)

Comment: Stupid answer, but amusing response :D